# xarray, Modul not found error. No module named xarray

Tags: python

I'm relativly new to coding.
Just wanted to code a short program that opens and reads my netCDF files via python, by watching a youtube tutorial.
But the problems started from the beginning.
The guy from the video imported xarray as xr, so i installed xarray in the conda prompt.
With pip freeze it shows, that I have successfully installed xarray.
The problem, when i code:
import xarray as xr,
the console shows the error: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xarray'".
Due to my lack of experience I have no clue how to solve this problem.
Thanks a lot.
Have a good one

I installed and unistalled xarray.
I created a new env.

Comment: Can you show us the line of code where this error occurs? It could be that you imported xarray as xr but went on to use xarray instead.

Comment: What IDE are you using and are you certain that this IDE where you are likely running your code has the correct virtual environment activated?